# How to import a custom java class to my Antlr Grammar?

Tags: java, antlr

In a directory called Test I have a java class in a file `Word.java` like this:

```
public class Word {
  public String value;

  public Word(String v) {
    value = v;
  }
}
```

And in the same directory my antlr4 grammar Test.g4 like this:

```
grammar Test;    
@header {
  import Test.Word;
}
@members {
  ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
}

program
@after { System.out.println(words.toString()); }
  : (ID { words.add(new Word($ID.text)); } )+
  ;
```

(In this example I'm just using Word instead of String to test the import thing. The grammar and the actions are not my problem yet)

Now, when I try to run `java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig Test` this is the outcome:

> blablabla
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test.Word
>
> blablabla

This is driving me crazy, how can I import my class in the .g4 file? I know that default java packages can be load but how do I import my custom java class?

**tl;dr: I created a java class and want to use it inside my antlr grammar. How can I do that?**

Comment: Thanks whoever downvoted my question without giving a reason. That's the right way to improve the community, downvote the question and let the guy figure out what he did wrong by himself. Nice job! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) will have to include dir containing Test.